# JavaScript - How do I get an element from an array after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html

I have some divs like this:

```css
.test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="one">1</div>
<div class="test" id="two">2</div>
<div class="test" id="three">3</div>
<div class="test" id="four">4</div>
<div class="test" id="five">5</div>
<div class="test" id="six">6</div>
<div class="test" id="seven">7</div>
```

their (id)s are different but I have applied the same class-name on them, 
So, I can now access them like this

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("clsname");
```

this created an array named box.
I want to write a JavaScript function that returns the clicked element in the array. 
For example, the function will be triggered when I click any of the box and will return the clicked box (div) element.

I want to do it with pure JS, no jquery, please :)

Thanks

Comment: _"but I have applied same classname on them"_ Not according to your example

Comment: I did not want to make the code messy, that's why said it below the code :)

Comment: Add some styling to this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy way to loop over them and add an event listener:

```
var testList = document.getElementsByClassName("clsname");

for(var i = 0; i < testList.length; i++) {
    testList[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

Here's a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/gajomuvote/edit?html,js,console,output) with an example on it.

What the code does is loop through the NodeList, then add an event listener on click to log their ID. Here's a snippet:

```js
var testList = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

for(var i = 0; i < testList.length; i++) {
    testList[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

```css
.test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one" class="test">1</div>
    <div id="two" class="test">2</div>
    <div id="three" class="test">3</div>
    <div id="four" class="test">4</div>
    <div id="five" class="test">5</div>
    <div id="six" class="test">6</div>
    <div id="seven" class="test">7</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want, you can use a `forEach` loop from Array like so:

```
var testList = document.getElementsByClassName("clsname");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(testList, function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient. If the list is thousands of elements. If new elements are added after the loop they won't have the listener attached either.

Comment: @jhummel That's very true, but if you had a document with thousands of elements, having each with an ID and class would be inefficient too. This suits the OPs needs and is not as inefficient for his use case.

Comment: I just feel like why add seven event listeners, when one is just as easy, more efficient and more future proof.

Comment: @jhummel I'm not opposed in the slightest to your idea. I agree yours is more efficient

Answer (score 2):

On ***DOMContentLoaded*** forEach element of document.getElementsByClassName("clsname") add the event handler:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("clsname")).forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      console.log(this.id);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="one" class="clsname">  111111111111</div>
<div id="two" class="clsname">  222222222222</div>
<div id="three" class="clsname">333333333333</div>
<div id="four" class="clsname"> 444444444444</div>
<div id="five" class="clsname"> 555555555555</div>
<div id="six" class="clsname">  666666666666</div>
<div id="seven" class="clsname">7777777777777</div>
```

Comment: Looks like we had the same idea, but very nice use of foreach!

Comment: And if you're using a recent version of browsers (except IE11, android browsers), you could use the spread operator: `[...document.getElementsByClassName("clsname")].forEach` instead of crusty old slice ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way of doing this would be to delegate the event to a parent wrapper.

```
<!-- add a surrounding div -->
<div id="myDiv">
  <div id="one" class="clsname"></div>
  <div id="two" class="clsname"></div>
  ...
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    // e.target was the clicked element, do something interesting with it.
    console.log(e.target);
  });
</script>
```

If you want to get fancy you could use the Element match API to ensure you have the correct element and not a child of the divs.

```
var el = e.target;
while(!el.matches("div.clss")) {
  el = el.parentNode;
}

// should always be the div and not some child element that was clicked.
console.log(el);
```

Comment: i think he is looking for class name not with id

Comment: @NalinAggarwal, this would still work with id or by class, one would just need to access either property from `e.target` and check it against an array. Or just check the element against the collection if storing `getElementsByClassName` result. Though the example should show that , instead of doing `return e.target` as that has no use here since it doesn't return to anything useful.

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to show that it's very inefficient to add event listeners to each element. What if that grows to be thousands of elements, or new elements are added via ajax, etc.